# Exclude liked and disliked pages in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm saving interests with likes and dislikes in those tables: `pages`, `pages_likes`, `pages_dislikes`

Now I wanted to have a main page to show a random page, but only those that haven't been liked or disliked by a specific user.

I have this SQL statement so far:

```
SELECT
   p.id AS page_id, d.uid AS duid, l.uid AS luid,p.title FROM OneNight_pages p

  LEFT JOIN OneNight_pages_dislikes d on d.page_id = p.id
  LEFT JOIN OneNight_pages_likes l on l.page_id = p.id
  WHERE 
  l.uid != 1 AND d.uid != 1
  GROUP BY page_id

ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10
```

I tested this without the `AND d.uid != 1` first and got the correct results. But after adding this AND-condition I get wrong results. He will only select a page that has been liked AND disliked and not filtering out this specific user-id like I want to.

How can I achieve to just exclude a specific user-id for both likes and dislikes? I guess a subquery or something would be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing the table structure, nor data sample, nor the expected results, so to be honest your question is not very clear.

I *guess* this is what you want:

```
SELECT p.id AS page_id, p.title
FROM OneNight_pages p
LEFT JOIN OneNight_pages_dislikes d ON (d.page_id = p.id AND d.uid = 1)
LEFT JOIN OneNight_pages_likes l ON (l.page_id = p.id AND l.uid = 1)
WHERE l.uid IS NULL AND d.uid IS NULL
GROUP BY page_id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 10
```

If that's indeed what you want, and if one user can like or dislike each page only once (i.e. if your primary key is `(page_id, uid)`), then the `GROUP BY` is probably unnecessary.

Also as a side note, unless your users can *both* like and dislike a page at the same time, it would make more sense to have only one table `likes` with a field that indicates if it's a like or a dislike (for example "1" for like "-1" for dislike).